# Check if value exists in two columns in VBA and highlight them, leaving out excess duplicates in either column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get VBA to look at values in one column, and then check if the same value exists in another column.

I am then trying to highlight the same number of cells in both columns where the same value shows up, meaning that if the same value shows up a different amount of times in one column than in the other, I need to highlight the same amount of cells in each column and leave any "excess" duplicate values without highlight.

The picture illustrates what I am trying to accomplish. [EXCEL SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTSbc.png)

As seen in the picture, the values have been highlighted to the degree that they show up in either column, leaving the additional duplicate values without highlight.

I tried this code but it did not work and highlighted cells that I did not expect to get highlighted. I tried to loop through the columns and ignore already highlighted cells.

```
Sub highlightMatchingValues()

'Declare variables
    Dim cellC As Range, cellE As Range

'Loop through each cell with a value in column C
       For Each cellC In Range("C:C").Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cellC) And cellC.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then 'ignore empty cells and cells that are already highlighted

'Loop through each cell with a value in column E
     For Each cellE In Range("E:E").Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(cellE) And cellE.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then 'ignore empty cells and cells that are already highlighted
                 If cellC.value = cellE.value Then 'check for a match

'Highlight both cells green
    cellC.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    cellE.Interior.Color = vbGreen


               End If
             End If
         Next cellE
    End If
    Next cellC

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here comes a solution that can solve your problem

```
'Sheet name = sheetName

'First columns variables (column C = index 3)
Dim firstLine1 As Long
Dim lastLine1 As Long

firstLine1 = 1
lastLine1 = Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    
'Second columns variables (column E = index 5)
Dim firstLine2 As Long
Dim lastLine2 As Long

firstLine2 = 1
lastLine2 = Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

'loop
For i = firstLine1 To lastLine1
    For j = firstLine2 To lastLine2
        If (Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(j, 5)) Then
            If (Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color <> vbGreen) Then
                Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I added this line to also skip blanks between Row 19 and 20;

If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)) And Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 5))) Then